# Do departure procedure speed restrictions override airspace speed restrictions?

Tags: faa-regulations, air-traffic-control, airspeed, sid-star, departure-sid

This is a speed restriction found on the BNGOS 3 RNAV Departure Procedure out of KOPF:

[image: KOPF BNGOS 3 DP Speed Restriction]

> SPEED: ACCELERATE TO 250 KT, IF UNABLE, ADVISE ATC

Opa Locka airport is Class D and is also below the Miami Class B airspace, so 14 CFR 91.117(b) & (c) would apply and we would be limited to 200 KIAS.

My questions are:

1. When should we accelerate to 250 KT?  I.e does the DP speed restriction override the 91.117 restrictions, and if not, do we need to advise ATC?
2. Are we expected to maintain 250 KT or is this considered a minimum speed (above 10,000 ft.)?

It seems like ATC wants us to accelerate asap (in fact, the old procedure used to say to accelerate “as rapidly as feasible” or something similar), but I don’t believe that we can until we either enter the Class B or leave the lateral limits.

Comment: That's been a long time, good to see you visiting. Welcome back!

Comment: @DeltaLima Yes, it has!  I’ve always lurked some and never really completely left, but life kept me too busy for too long, lol.

Comment: [CFR 91.117](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-F/part-91/subpart-B/subject-group-ECFRe4c59b5f5506932/section-91.117) part b) allows ATC leeway. c) seems pretty airtight.  But d) seems to allow some discretion, especially if ATC is informed.  Class D requires two-way communication anyways.

Answer (score 2):

You should remain below 200 knots while under class B. Accelerate to 250 knots once you leave the lateral boundaries of class B or enter the class B, whichever comes first.

The 91.117(b) restriction includes the language "Unless otherwise authorized or required by ATC," but the 91.117(c) restriction does not. You may not accelerate above 200 knots below class B airspace, regardless of what ATC says.

91.117(d) always applies- if the aircraft you are flying can't climb safely at 200 knots then you should fly at your minimum safe climb airspeed.

Based on the wording, I wouldn't necessarily interpret this as a maximum speed. But of course you need to maintain 250 until above 10000 feet.

Comment: [Opa Locka](https://www.miami-airport.com/opalocka.asp) is described on the website as a "reliever to Miami International Airport".  This would indicate that, under local rules, it might share speed limits for  **jets**.  Both airports share the same departure frequency 119.45.  It would be understandable that ATC would want the same speed for **departing** jets for safer spacing.

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni It's understandable but the regulation is clear that ATC doesn't have authority to waive 91.117(c) speed limits.

Comment: I agree.  But d) may apply for a local situation, especially since Opa Locka is essentially a satellite of Miami Int.  Sort of where business jets can avoid some of the congestion of the main hub.  Worth looking into, but if ATC (and the plate) says 250 knots, what is one to do?  (In controlled airspace).

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni Same thing as if a controller told you to maintain 300 knots below 10000 or gave you VFR vectors into class B without a clearance. "Unable." I'm not really convinced that 250 is the "minimum safe airspeed" per 91.117(d), particularly since it just says to notify ATC if you can't accelerate to 250.

Comment: Generally, one follows orders and then reports it, unless the craft is in danger.  I wonder if anyone reported it already, and what the response was.

Comment: @Chris Regarding your last paragraph, should we assume that it's a minimum speed then?  This is the problem that I have with the wording.  It's ambiguous about what to do, and I'm looking for clear guidance on what they actually expect. 

Comment: @chris Also, are we supposed to "ADVISE ATC" (per the restriction) that we are unable to accelerate to 250 KT due to the Class B overhead?  I wish that the procedure designers would just say "...as soon as practical after leaving the lateral limits of, or upon entering the Class B" or something similar.  Then there's no ambiguity (although one could argue that there isn't any ambiguity because there's a regulation that covers it, I suppose....)

Comment: @Lnafziger Agree it's unclear. I suspect it's because the same language is used for KMIA's BNGOS3 departure, where you start out in class B so there's no ambiguity. Might be worth sending the FAA a message to clarify.

Comment: @Lnafziger I would interpret it as a minimum speed. Which combined with 91.117(a) makes it a mandatory speed below 10000. The BNGOS4 departure that just finished its comment period changes the language to "ACCELERATE TO 250 KIAS UNTIL LEAVING 10000", which is clearer.

Comment: Thanks, the BBGOS4 language is much clearer as far as how long the speed is applicable, and implies that other people found it ambiguous too!

Comment: Also, since the questions asks the more generic questions about "airspace restrictions" vs DP restrictions, what if this was at a different airport that didn't underlie Class B?  Would the DP require that you accelerate to 250 within the Class D?  I.e. would it now be authorized in accordance with 91.117, or is that a different mechanism/ATC procedure?

Comment: @Lnafziger Yes, I would interpret that as authorization. Though asking and specifically being told to fly 250 knots would be even better.

Comment: If you would like to incorporate these comments into your answer to make it more complete, I'll go ahead and accept it (and we can get rid of the comments)!